# Build state machine with 2 variables

Tags: state-machine, modelica, stateflow

I am new with Modelica but I would like to build an easy state machine with 2 variables :
The initial step is "off" (the variable Light_cabin==0) then if button_Evac == 1 (second variable) then go to step "on" and Light_Cabin == 1 if Button_Evac==0 return to initial step.
This is my state machine :
[state_machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BUBD.png)

But when I launched the simulation Light_Cabin = 0 even if button_Evac = 1 and the active step is the initial step.

This is my code :

```
model StateMachine

block Off
  outer output Integer Light_Cabin;
equation 
Light_Cabin = 0;
end Off;

block On
  outer output Integer Light_Cabin;
equation 
  Light_Cabin = 1;
end On;

  parameter Integer Button_Evac(start=0);
  inner Integer Light_Cabin(start=0);

  Off off;
  On on;

equation 
  transition(
    off,
    on,
    Button_Evac == 1,
    immediate=true,
    reset=false,
    synchronize=false,
    priority=1); 
  transition(
    on,
    off,
    Button_Evac == 0,
    immediate=true,
    reset=false,
    synchronize=false,
    priority=1);

  initialState(off);
end StateMachine;
```

If you have any idea where my error is please let me know.
Thank you for your help,
Eloise

Comment: Can you post the code? Difficult to help with only the screenshot...

Comment: Yes I just edited my post thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the design of state machines in Modelica, as can be seen in https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch17.html#semantics-summary

- Even though the transition is immediate the state is active one clock tick. If that wasn't the case there would be a risk of infinite loops if all transitions are immediate - which would require additional semantic checks.
- It technically not starting in "off", but a separate "initial state" and in the first clock tick the state machine transitions to "off" and thus cannot transition further in that clock tick.

Comment: The default clock is 1s, so simulating for longer than 1s will show the change of `Light_Cabin` in case `Button_Evac==1`. This is done after 1s as a result of what is explained in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I changed the period of the clock but it hasn't changed the value of Light_Cabin. If I create another state "Initial state" what's the transition to go to "Initial state" to "Off" ? Is the transition "at the first clock tick" ? If so I don't really know how to write it because I am very new to the Modelica language.